# How to delete data of existing app when updating to newer version

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

Im using Xamarin Forms for my app, I have read that when you uninstall the app, all existing data of the app is removed. If I update the existing app the old data is still retained.

My question is how do I delete data of previous app? 
I'm using Settings Plugin which has Clear functionality and sqlLite where I can  delete the tables and add again.

Is this correct? And do I need to delete any other data?

Comment: the only data you need to worry about is anything that YOU created in the first place

Comment: @Jason thanks, okay I will delete that data itself. :)